# using POST to store user information in web server IOS app

Tags: php, ios, json, xcode, swift

I'm building an IOS app using Swift + xcode7 + php scripts + mysql server side (Bluehost) it is actually my first project using xcode

When I try to store user information into the database nothing happened and no error messages appear plus there is no row added.

Here is my code , I tried to inspect it but nothing seems to be wrong.

```
// send user data to a server side



let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://thetogo.net/userRegister.php");
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

let postString = "email=\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword)";
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);




        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data,response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            do {

            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json{
                let resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
                print("result: \(resultValue)")

                var isUserRegistered:Bool = false;
                if(resultValue=="Success") { isUserRegistered = true; }

                var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
                if(!isUserRegistered){
                    messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    //DisplayAlertMessage with confirmation
                    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message:messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default){ action in
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
                    }
                    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated:true, completion: nil);
                });



                }} catch {
                    print(error)
            }
         }
```

And this is my php code

```
<?php 


require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");

$email = htmlentities($_POST["email"]);
$password = htmlentities($_POST["password"]);

$returnValue = array();

if(empty($email) || empty($password))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "Missing required field";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetails($email);

if(!empty($userDetails))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "User already exists";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$secure_password = md5($password); // I do this, so that user password cannot be read even by me

$result = $dao->registerUser($email,$secure_password);

if($result)
{
$returnValue["status"] = "Success";
$returnValue["message"] = "User is registered";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$dao->closeConnection();

?>
```

Comment: Based on what you posted the only thing I could guess would be that it's not connecting to your database properly. And since that's in another class I can't see if there's error checks for that connection, etc that would show up if that was indeed the cause.

Comment: @pbush25 the connection is properly fine I tried that locally and it worked fine

Comment: Well then I would get out your debugger, I would recommend a tool called Charles which you can use to monitor your network transmissions to your website so you can tell whether what's being transmitted is what you expect and then you can see the response too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.) Write below code in your php code to check errors :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

> 2.) Use $_GET http method and hit url directly on browser.
>
> After doing this you will see what error you are facing. After solving
>   error just replace $_GET to $_POST